# Extraer valor de cadena de texto

Tags: c#, substring

necesito extraer un valor concreto de una cadena de texto:

```
 "Persist Security Info=True;Server=PCHOME\MSSQL;Database=master;Connection Timeout=1800;Uid=User;Pwd=$2%4ff2;"
```

Lo que necesito es solo el valor de Server, es decir "*PCHOME\MSSQL*", me estoy peleando con `Substring`, pero me da que tiene que haber un modo más eficiente para hacerlo.
¿Alguien me puede guiar un poco por favor?

Comment: La cadena siempre tiene el mismo formato?  Es decir, la propiedad "Server" siempre viene en la segunda posicion?

Comment: Si, siempre tiene el mismo formato.

Comment: Podrías colocar el codigo que tienes hasta ahora, lo que has intentado.? En todo caso yo te sugiero utilizar una expresión regular (seria mas rápida) o simplemente partir la cadena entre los ; y recorrerla haciendo un split en = para saber en que posición vas.

Comment: El `split` es justo lo que andaba buscando, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener los valores y almacenarlos en un [**Dictionary**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) de esta forma en base a su "key" podrías usarlos en tu programa, ejemplo:

```
        string cadena = "Persist Security Info=True;Server=PCHOME\\MSSQL;Database=master;Connection Timeout=1800;Uid=User;Pwd=$2%4ff2;";
        var valores = cadena.Split(';');
        Dictionary<string, string> valoresConexion = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        
        foreach (string valor in valores)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valor)) { 
               valoresConexion.Add(valor.Split('=')[0], valor.Split('=')[1]);
            }
        }
```

Como ejemplo de esta forma puedes pedir el valor deseado mediante el  [**Dictionary**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) en base a su llave `valoresConexion["<key>"]`:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Persist Security Info:  " + valoresConexion["Persist Security Info"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Server:  " + valoresConexion["Server"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Database:  " + valoresConexion["Database"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Timeout:  " + valoresConexion["Connection Timeout"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Uid:  " + valoresConexion["Uid"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Pwd:  " + valoresConexion["Pwd"]);
```

Salida:

```
Persist Security Info:  True
Server:  PCHOME\MSSQL
Database:  master
Connection Timeout:  1800
Uid:  User
Pwd:  $2%4ff2
```

Comment: Genial. Muchas, muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente @MiguelAngel recuerda , cuando preguntes trata de agregar lo que estés tratando, o investigado, en este caso mencionar que buscaste sobre Dictionary, ,saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar la funcion `Split()` asi:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var cadena = "Persist Security Info=True;Server=PCHOME\\MSSQL;Database=master;Connection Timeout=1800;Uid=User;Pwd=$2%4ff2;";
        var valores = cadena.Split(';');
        var server = valores[1].Split('=');
        Console.WriteLine(server[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

vamos con substring, así no andamos ocupando memoria de mas...

```
int inicio = cadena.IndexOf("Server=")+7;
int fin = cadena.IndexOf(";Data=");
string s = cadena.substring(inicio, fin-inicio);
```

Con esto también podrías controlar que realmente la cadena que buscas existe. si inicio o fin no existen, entonces no esta la cadena

Answer (score -1):

He hecho:

```
 string cadena = "Persist Security Info=True;Server=PCHOME\\MSSQL;Database=master;Connection Timeout=1800;Uid=User;Pwd=$2%4ff2;";
    var valores = cadena.Split(';');
    List<string[]> coleccion = new List<string[]>();
    foreach(string valor in valores)
    {
                coleccion.Add(valor.Split('='));
    }
```

Así recojo todos los key,valor en una lista.

Comment: La pregunta dice que desea "extraer un valor concreto", no todos :|

Comment: Lo siento, soy un avaricioso :p

Comment: hehehe! @MiguelAngel , sabes me has dado una idea, si deseas obtener todos los valores para poder usar alguno definido por su key, puedes usar un Dictionary!

Comment: Justamente me estaba peleando intentado averiguar una forma de acceder fácilmente a un valor buscando su key en la lista, voy a probar con un Dictionary.
Esto ya no tiene nada que ver con lo que necesitaba, pero aprendo un montón.

Comment: Agregue una respuesta, de esa forma los almacenarías y si deseas alguno pues solo defines el nombre de la llave, @MiguelAngel saludos.

Comment: ESto en realidad no responde a la pregunta ni de casualidad :/

Comment: Qué va, pero una cosa ha llevado a la otra... :_